# T-SQL : using parameter as an operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to parameterize the arithmetic operators (<, >, =, >=, <=) in T-SQL?

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @Operator 

SET @Operator = '>=' 

SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE Date @Operator '7/1/2017'
```

Also, I am testing to add additional parameter using functions `EXEC('SELECT SiteLongName, * FROM Reporting.Survey_Details WHERE CallDate ' + @Operator +  '''7/1/2017''' + 'and SiteLongName in (select value from dbo.FnSplit(''' + @Site + ''''+'',''+'',''))` , but it is erroring out.

Comment: A `case` expression can be used, e.g. `case when @Operator = '>=' and Col >= @Val then 1 when @Operator = '=' and Col = @Val then 1 ... else 0 end = 1`, but the performance would be an issue. For a small dataset it may suffice. And it avoids meeting [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: performance will be an issue for the report I'm building in SSRS as it contains huge monthly call data with several report parameters. I'm only concern about using the arithmetic operator as a parameter, but now im testing the incorporation of a sql function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can if you use dynamic SQL.

Example :

```
DECLARE @Operator VARCHAR(2)

SET @Operator = '>='

EXEC('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Date ' + @Operator +  ' ''7/1/2017''')
```

As you can see in the example, handling quotes in dynamic SQL can be a pain. Though it's no big deal in your example.

Be aware that without proper care, dynamic SQL open a vulnerability in your system where user could use [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks against your program.

Comment: What if I want another parameter @Site? how do Incorporate that? EXEC('SELECT * FROM Reporting.Survey_Details WHERE CallDate ' + @Operator +  '''7/1/2017''' + '[SiteLongName] = ' + @Site) ??

Comment: @arsee yes, this is what you have to do. Be careful of spaces when concatenating parts of the dynamic query. Missing spaces will get you an incorrect syntax error in the final query. Since it's dynamic, you only know at run time if the final query compile or not.

Comment: @arsee also this is where it's become tricker, because if `@site` contain `'`, it will break the query. You have to double quotes in there with something like this : `REPLACE(@site, '''', '''''')`.

Comment: the site does not contain an apostrophe.. it does have a space in between for 2 word like 'Los Angeles'

Comment: @arsee space doesn't break anything. ` '[SiteLongName] = ''' + @site + ''' `.
I would suggest you to use [print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql) for small dynamic query to see what is the final query and fix syntaxes issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150345/discussion-between-arsee-and-axmim).